# Adding a huge number of lines to a diagram

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a table with 600+ lines, and wish to add each of these to a chart. All lines have the same x-data, in this case the years (2013-2015).

```
Fruit   Name            2013    2014    2015
Pear    Type A           120     130     150
Pear    Type B                    90     110
Apple   Gravensteiner     70      80      90
Apple   Cox's Orange      80      90      90
Banana  Thomson          200     210     220
```

The label is the Name (Gravensteiner etc). See example diagram from table's data.

[image]

Can I do this (semi-)automatically? I have some experience with scripting Excel, but it's been a while now...

Answer (score 1):

#### I have a table with 600+ lines, and wish to add each of these to a chart.

It is not possible.

You are allowed a maximum of 255 data series in one chart.

---

#### Charting specifications and limits

```
Feature                                         Maximum limit
Charts linked to a worksheet                    Limited by available memory
Worksheets referred to by a chart               255
Data series in one chart                        255
Data points in a data series for 2-D charts     Limited by available memory
Data points in a data series for 3-D charts     Limited by available memory
Data points for all data series in one chart    Limited by available memory
```

Source [Excel specifications and limits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-ca36e2dc-1f09-4620-b726-67c00b05040f)

Comment: Aw, crap. Can one dynamically add lines once a selection has been made?

Comment: No idea, but if I had to guess it would be no.